# Implement readInt and readUTF for php file operation?

Tags: php, file, stream, filereader, filewriter

If my writeInt() and writeUTF() looks like :

```
function write_int($value)
{
    $data = pack('N', $value);
    fwrite($this->file, $data);    #$this->file is get by fopen($path,"wb")
}

function write_utf($value)
{
    $this->write_int(strlen($value));
    fwrite($this->file,$value);
}
```

How to read it ? I try :

```
function read_int()
{
    $data = fread($this->file, 4);        #$this->file is get by fopen($path,"rb")
    return unpack('N', $data);            #unpack return array , not int
}

function read_utf($value)
{
    $l = $this->read_int();               #unpack return array , not int
    return fread($this->file,$l);         #type mismatch
}
```

You can see the mismatch of type.

By the way you can change the format of my writeInt and writeUTF . I only want a way to write and read for file

Answer (score 0):

That function returns the binary data of the variable you are reading. You have to compose it into the desired data type. In the case of int, for example, reading the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php states that `N` will pack a 4-byte long integer into a big endian byte array.

This code shows how to rebuild it

```
function read_int()
{
    $data = fread($this->file, 4);        #$this->file is get by fopen($path,"rb")
    $raw = unpack('N', $data);            #unpack return array , not int
    $val = (($raw[3] & 0xff) | ($raw[2] << 16) & 0xff00 | ($raw[1]  << 8) & 0xff0000 | ($raw[0] << 24) & 0xff0000);
    return $val;
}
```

You can use this logic to rebuild other variables. In the case of Strings, the byte is simply the int val of the character, so you only need to cast it.